# Please rename [youtube-creatorstudio] to [youtube-creator-studio]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [youtube-creatorstudio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creatorstudio) should be renamed to [youtube-creator-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creator-studio) better to reflect the tool kit's official name.

[image: WAmeta example]

It's a minor tag with just three questions but I can't think of any reason not to use the facility's proper name. The tools referred to are clearly those at https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U.

If we must have tag [youtube-creatorstudio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-creatorstudio) please can we at least have the second 'space' (hyphen) in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All set.  I just retagged the questions with the new tag.